# Why KNN in rapidminer is giving memory problems?

Tags: rapidminer, text-classification

I am working in text classification on 20NewsGroup dataset with 100 documents in each category. I classify text documents via Naive Bayes using 10-fold cross validation, It runs successfully and give me results at the end.

I tried same with KNN with 10-fold cross validation but it always ends in "Process Failure" which shows that it requires more memory than available. I increase heap space for rapidminer from 1GB to 2.5G in build.xml as well as rapidminerGUI.bat but nothing improves(so i assume heap space is not a problem) and it always ends up in demanding more memory.

Kindly help, i am stuck out at it and tried every possible option i could think about

Platform Details:

OS: Windows 7(64 bit)
Software Version: Rapidminer 5.3 (64 bit)
Java: Java 1.7 (64 bit)

Comment: what are the input you have given to KNN

Comment: @Ashish Text documents from directories(Preprocessing/ tf-idf applied) in the form of example set...

Comment: ok document term matrix you have generated

Comment: actually m also working on text categorization m also stuck in KNN

Comment: @Ashish you may also want to look into this thread i have seen it but i am not sure that this problem would exist for smaller datasets or not... (http://rapid-i.com/rapidforum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=1237.0)

Comment: Actually after generating doc-term matrix i have performed IG and PCA then i got some selected words then i have apply KNN but m confused how to proceed

Comment: I did'nt applied any feature reduction or feature selection approach in rapidminer and in fact i am newbie to rapidminer, however i do try out them in weka and find out IG improves KNN performance as KNN deals better with lower dimensions whereas PCA decrease accuracy of KNN in my case.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47549/discussion-between-ashish-and-kashif-khan)

Answer (score 0):

How many attributes are there in the example set that is passed to the k-nn operator?

Comment: 183257 but i came to know that rapidminer use a very heavy format for keeping the example set in ram which is the cause of running me out of memory, so i decided to use feature selection (weight by IG) to reduce dimensions. I received weights after "Weight by IG" operator but don't know how to convert those weighted attributes into wordlist (as i have seperate dedicated test set) ....!!

Comment: Use the `Select by Weight` operator with the `weight relation` parameter set to `top k` and `k` equal to the number of attributes you want to keep.

Comment: Yes its fine but i want my test set also to keep identical "k" attributes as the train set has so i may need to provide the output of "Select by Weight" operator to "Process Documents From File" which i have used for loading test file set which should be word list but it give me weights on the output. How can i convert that output (weights0 into word list or perhaps i am making any mistake in understanding ?

Comment: It's difficult to be precise without your process in front of me but normally the word list created during the training phase is passed to the `process documents` operator during the test phase. If there is additional weighting done during the training phase, the weights can be used during the test phase after the `process documents`. It is possible to create a word list in the training phase from the result of the weighting operation but it's a bit more advanced.

Comment: i have created a ticket on stackoverflow regarding my problem with snapshot of my process, perhaps it may shows my intention more clearly   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21853989/how-to-apply-informationgain-in-rapidminer-with-seperate-test-set